# If I chdir within a thread, will that affect the cwd of the parent program?

Tags: c, pthreads, chdir

If I chdir within a thread, will that affect the cwd of the parent program?

Comment: How about you give it a try and let us know?

Comment: With parent program, do you mean the thread's process or the parent process of the thread's process?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes.

If you need relative paths in a multithreaded application, it's safest to use the `at()` versions of functions.  For example, `openat()` is like `open()`:

```
int openat(int dirfd, const char *pathname, int flags);
```

The first parameter is the fd to a directory.  The path is relative to that directory.

Comment: Then what's the alternative for copying a file up a directory? I don't want to do an absolute path for the write() call. If chdir'ing isn't thread-safe, and I have a number of threads copying files from one folder to its parent folder, how can this be done?

Comment: On recent POSIX systems, you can use the "at" functions: `openat()`, for example.  They let you work with paths relative to a directory.  You open the directory as a file descriptor, then you can open files relative to it.

Comment: This is a very helpful answer except than I am sufficiently New2This that I do not know how to create a directory file descriptor. Nor can I find any internet examples for it...

Comment: @New2This: It's a regular file descriptor.  You use `open()` or `openat()`, just like with files.  (You can't read from the descriptor, though.)

Answer (score 2):

On both Linux and macOS, there is a per-thread current directory which can override the process-wide current directory. It is not set by default, and the APIs to set it are completely non-portable (not standardised by anything).

On Linux, your thread needs to call `unshare(CLONE_FS)` to make its filesystem information (root directory, current directory and umask) independent of the rest of the process. Having done that, subsequent calls to `chdir` (and also `chroot` and `umask`) will impact that thread only, and not the other threads in the process. Note this is irreversible: once the thread's filesystem information is disconnected from the process, there is no way to reconnect it – keep that in mind if you use thread pools.

On macOS, there are two undocumented APIs, `pthread_chdir_np` and `pthread_fchdir_np`, which are like `chdir` and `fchdir`, just per-thread rather than per-process. These are not in the public headers, but you can copy their declarations from Apple's open source libpthread source code's [`private/pthread/private.h`](https://github.com/apple-oss-distributions/libpthread/blob/libpthread-485.40.4/private/pthread/private.h#L41):

```
__API_AVAILABLE(macos(10.12), ios(10.0), tvos(10.0), watchos(3.0))
int pthread_chdir_np(const char *path);

__API_AVAILABLE(macos(10.12), ios(10.0), tvos(10.0), watchos(3.0))
int pthread_fchdir_np(int fd);
```

Note that, unlike Linux, this actually can be reversed by calling `pthread_fchdir_np(-1)`, which will clear out the per-thread current directory and go back to inheriting that of the process – if you are using a thread pool (such as libdispatch), cleaning up after yourself by calling `pthread_fchdir_np(-1)` is very important, otherwise you may encounter hard-to-diagnose bugs (some thread randomly having an unexpected current directory).

As undocumented interfaces, Apple could *in theory* discontinue (or incompatibly change) them at any time. However, given that [Google Chrome](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/refs/tags/108.0.5325.3/base/process/launch_mac.cc#28) (among other apps) is using these functions, I'd be rather surprised if Apple were ever to do that.

Also, as the Chromium source mentions, while these pthread library calls were only added in 10.12, they are thin wrappers over the `__pthread_chdir` and `__pthread_fchdir` system calls which have existed since 10.5. If (for some reason) your code still needs to support macOS 10.5–10.11, you could do so by calling those system calls directly.

I'm not aware of any other common platforms having a per-thread current working directory. In particular, there is no such concept on Windows. One should avoid doing this (use `openat` for example) unless one has no other choice.

Comment: Thanks for this usefull information. But unfortunately using Google Chrome as an example why they wont remove it is just plain wrong and the opposite. Chrome is maybe one of the only apps that always get updated by users on all platforms and therefore it would adapt somehow within a short period of time.

Comment: On Windows you can at least replace some calls like CreateFile via the NT system call level which has the same concept of providing a directory handle to as current working directory. It's in the code since 1998 with WinNT 4.5 and if you dig hard enough for documentation, it's even officially and was introduced with the posix subsystem (which also allows ":" in file path names and the same unlink semantic for files that unix has). I have to say, i only played with it and don't know how many calls can be substituted with "at" like functions, i know that Linux stopped half way.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the "parent program" (initial thread of the thread's process) will be affected because  the current directory is shared by all threads of a process.

http://linux.die.net/man/7/pthreads