# chdir() & multithreading in C

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, chdir

Is it possible to use `chdir()` or some other command to change the directory in a thread without affecting the cwd of the other threads ? I'm using `pthread.h`.

*I'm trying to write a server program that handles multiple client connections and requests. One of the available commands to the client is the `'cd'` command.

Comment: This sounds scary. What are you trying to achieve? Maybe by formulating the root cause more help can be offered.

Comment: The question has been updated

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, as mentioned by others the current working directory is a per-process property, not per-thread. You can "emulate" a per-thread (or per client, or however you structure your application) current working directory by storing a file descriptor for the "per-thread CWD" and the using the various *at() syscalls specified in POSIX 2008 (openat() etc.) to manipulate paths relative to that directory fd.

Comment: +1 I was going to spitball the *at calls as well.  Rather than a definitive "no" they provides some opportunity for OP to reach his goals depending on what he plans.

Answer (score 4):

No, it isn't. The current working directory is a process wide setting, not a thread setting.

Your best bet is to explicitly access files in a directory using the full path, rather than changing to that directory in order to do so.

Comment: Could you provide any reference (POSIX, maybe)? The last time I looked for exactly this issue, I found nothing but a vage sense of implementation-defined-ness.

Comment: As [janneb](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23516195/63743) notes the so-call *at() calls can also be used.  Whether they are enough to get OP over the goal line is something he will have to determine.  Even using both methods its a bit tricky to emulate being in the cwd.

Answer (score 1):

Answering the updated question:

For each client you will need a client structure, which amongst other things (Id, Ip, anything you might consider important) also holds the directory the client is visualizing right now (assuming you do something like this).

So when a request from the client comes you already know in which directory that client works.

Comment: Ok, but what if a client try to change the directory? I mean wich command should I use instead of chdir() ?

Comment: what do you want the client to do in the directory?

Comment: If you want to list files in a directory and send back to the client: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4204666/how-to-list-files-in-a-directory-in-a-c-program and just use the directory of the client.

Answer (score 0):

On some platforms, the answer is **yes**. While the POSIX standard specifies the current working directory as *per-process* not *per-thread*, some platforms provide a per-thread working directory as a non-standard extension. To my knowledge, the only platforms having this feature are Linux and XNU (macOS/iOS/etc), although their APIs for setting the per-thread working directory are fundamentally incompatible with each other. If those are the only platforms you need to support, you could use their per-thread working directory support.

However, it would mean your software (or this aspect of it) would be fundamentally non-portable – it is never going to work on Windows, Cygwin, FreeBSD/OpenBSD/NetBSD, Solaris/Illumos, AIX, etc, since those platforms lack the concept of a per-thread working directory. It is *possible* one or more of them may add that support in the future, but there's no guarantee that will happen for any of them, and it could be years away even if it does.

In terms of details of the Linux and Apple APIs to do this, I explained it in [my answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73867506/2147204), so I won't repeat those details here.